# CSS, img hover inside <a> tag affecting next img's opacity

Tags: css

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="images/states/oregon.png" name="oregon" width="115" height="98" class="state" id="oregon" />
</a>
<img src="images/states/plates/oregon.png" name="oregon_plate" width="109" height="59" class="license_plate" id="oregon_plate" />
```

On hover of the first image in the `<a>` tag, I need the second image's opacity to increase using CSS.  I have tried using the  `+`and `~` operators and couldn't get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The second image isn't a sibling of the first. It is a sibling of the first's parent link.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I couldn't figure it out...kind of almost seems like a silly question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a:hover + img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The second `img` is a sibling of the `a`, so `+` will do the job.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnK5M/1/)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answers.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
a + #oregon_plate
{
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out; /*opacity decreases smoothly*/
}
a:hover + #oregon_plate {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

There is a fiddle for you here

http://jsfiddle.net/u6rKy/